# Multiple rows insertion into sql based on multiple ids

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I want to insert three values or three rows for each user I have. I know I can use the following query

```
INSERT INTO subscriptions(id_account, subscription) 
SELECT id_account, 'subscriptionVAlue' FROM   unnest ('{123,456,789}'::int[]) id;
```

to insert one row for each id in the list. 
but I want is something like this

```
INSERT INTO subscriptions (account_id, subscription, i18nkey) 
VALUES (id, 'subscription1', 'translation1')
VALUES (id, 'subscription2', 'translation2')
VALUES (id, 'subscription3', 'translation3')
where id in (123,1234,410,4512);
```

This is such bad query I know, but I want similar kind of behavior. Is that possible?

Comment: You are not using MySQL.  What database are you really using?

Comment: sorry the example query i provided was wrong... my mistake. I am using mySQL though.

Comment: you can use transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross join`:

```
INSERT INTO subscriptions (account_id, subscription, i18nkey) 
    SELECT a.account_id, subscription, i18nkey
    FROM (SELECT 'subscription1' as subscription, 'translation1' as i18nkey UNION ALL
          SELECT 'subscription2', 'translation2' UNION ALL
          SELECT 'subscription3', 'translation3'
         ) x CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT 123 as account_id UNION ALL SELECT 1234 UNION ALL
          SELECT 410 UNION ALL SELECT 4512
         ) a;
```

`unnest()` is not MySQL syntax.  You can also do something similar with `unnest()`.  The above should work in almost any database, although you might need a `FROM` clause (such as `FROM dual`) for the subqueries.